# API Platform GraphQL creates generically typed IterableConnection with entity specific connection for related entities

Tags: api-platform.com

### Summary

When creating two entities with a relation, and at the same time using a custom `DataProvider` *(implementing `CollectionDataProviderInterface` and `RestrictedDataProviderInterface`)*, the GraphQL schema generates a generic `IterableConnection` instead of a Connection *specific* for the relation.

**Works:** `Book` *(example entity provided by api-platform which uses Doctrine ORM)* has the following GraphQL field:

```
reviews(
    first: Int
    last: Int
    before: String
    after: String
): ReviewConnection  # Connection which is specific to Reviews
```

**Does not work:** `Agent` *(customer entity using a custom DataProvider)* has the following GraphQL field:

```
dept(
    first: Int
    last: Int
    before: String
    after: String
): IterableConnection  # <-- Connection which is generic, expected DepartmentConnection
```

### Detailed description

The example entities provided in the documentation under [Getting Started with API Platform: Hypermedia and GraphQL API, Admin and Progressive Web App](https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/#bringing-your-own-model): `Book` and `Review`, works correctly out of the box.
The `Book` entity will have a GraphQL field called `reviews` which is of type `ReviewConnection`.

So for instance a `Book` could be queried like this:

```
{
  book(id: "/books/1") {
    reviews {   # type: ReviewConnection
      edges {   # type: [ReviewEdge]
        node {  # type: Review
          id
          body
          publicationDate
          book {
            description
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However for the custom entities, using a custom `DataProvider`, the connections are typed as a generic `IterableConnection`. This makes it impossible to query the related entity using GraphQL, since the entity behind the connection is not known. The rest API still works though, so from the looks of it the entities and DataProviders are indeed correct.

The corresponding query for an `Agent` would look like this:

```
{
  agent(id: "/agents/1") {
    dept {     # type: IterableConnection
      edges {  # type: [IterableEdge] (expected type: [DepartmentEdge])
        node   # type: Iterable (expected type: Department)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also when executing this GraphQL query, the following exception is thrown:

```
Argument 1 passed to ApiPlatform\\Core\\GraphQl\\Serializer\\SerializerContextBuilder::replaceIdKeys()
must be of the type array, bool given, called in
/srv/api/vendor/api-platform/core/src/GraphQl/Serializer/SerializerContextBuilder.php on line 72
```

Basically it boils down to that in `SerializerContextBuilder.php` on line 72 the variable $fields will look like this for a `Book`:

```
$fields = [
    'reviews' => [
        'edges' => [
            'node' => [
                'id' => true
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

While for an `Agent` it will lack the last array level with the `'id'`:

```
$fields = [
    'dept' => [
        'edges' => [
            'node' => true
        ]
    ]
];
```

However, I figured the Exception *is not* the root cause in that sense - because the error is already at the point when the schema is generated.

I cannot figure out where the problem lies, if it's on the entity, DataProvider or somewhere else.

The `Book` entity, which works correctly, looks exactly as in the documentation.

The relevant parts are basically:

```php
/**
 * @var Review[] Available reviews for this book.
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Review", mappedBy="book", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
public $reviews;
```

Here it seems to be enough to type the property as `@var Review[]`, and the GraphQL field called `review` will automatically be of type `ReviewConnection`, and thus containing the schema of the `Review` entity.

The custom entity `Agent` however, which doesn't work as expected, looks basically the same, but without the ORM annotations:

```php
/**
 * @var Department[]
 */
public $dept;
```

It works to query both `agent` and `agents`, and also `department` and `departments` in GraphQL. This means that the DataProviders works, and that the schema generated for a single entity is correct, but not the connection to related entites.

Any suggestions grately appreciated!